# Create a geometry so every square is exactly surrounded by 7 other squares

Tags: pattern, geometry

At 4x4 table, every square in the middle is surrounded by 8 other squares,
every square at the sides is surrounded by 5 other squares,
and every square at the corners is surrounded by 3 other squares.

```
3 5 5 3
5 8 8 5
5 8 8 5
3 5 5 3
```

Create a geometry structure so every perfect square  is exactly surrounded by 7 other squares.

Note : The squares are equal size

Comment: squares of equal size?

Comment: yes, perfect squares of equal size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a

> cube

and divide each of its faces in half twice to make four squares.  Each square touches

> the three other squares on the same face, and two squares on each adjacent face

for a total of seven.

---

Alternate answer:

Take a 3x3 grid of squares and

> remove the center square.

Then

> tile the plane

with the resulting shape.

Each square on the edge of the 3x3 tile touches

> four squares in the same tile, and three squares in the adjacent tile.

Each square in the corner of the 3x3 tile touches

> two squares in the same tile, two squares in each of the edge-adjacent tiles, and one square in the diagonally adjacent tile.